# Sub-band partitioning of filter-banks

Tags: filters, frequency, filter-bank

In [ECE-700 Filterbank Notes](http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~schniter/ee700/handouts/filterbanks.pdf) the partitioning is $ \Delta = \frac{2\pi}{M}$ with center-frequencies at $ \omega_k = \frac{2\pi}{M}k$ which makes me wonder, considering that frequencies in the range from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ are just the negative versions of the range from $0$ to $\pi$, which divide into  low- and high-pass frequencies.

In the follow-up picture the partitioning then stretches from $0$ to $\pi$ - is there someone so nice as to explain to me what I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 1):

The notes made me wonder as well, and I cannot suspect the author made a mistake. The first graph with periodicity is generic. The second one corresponds to dyadic iteration (wavelets), often displayed in $[0,\pi]$, except when dealing with complex wavelets where  $[-\pi,\pi]$ is used. I agree, $[0,2\pi]$ could have been used instead, but I have never seen the $2^k$ partitioning mirrored at the end.

You can see from the rest of the paper that the author uses $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the author is only showing [0,π] for simplicity. This is often done in textbooks on the subject as well.

A full implementation would indeed have filters with centers that fill the range of [0,2π] or [-π, π], however you wish to visualize the spectrum. You are correct that for real signals, the negative frequencies are just a mirror of the positives; this however is not the case for a complex valued input signal, where the entire interval of [-π, π] can be unique. Nevertheless, for a near perfect reconstruction filter bank, our filters should cover the entire spectrum, such that no information is lost.

Summary: [0,π] is shown for simplicity. Realistically, the filters cover the full [0, 2π] swath.